# Parsing JSON Within JSON in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm trying to store the JSON that is within the JSON i get from the following request...

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.demo.com/server/rest/login?username=admin&password=123"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                    completionHandler:
                          ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                              if (error) {
                                  // Handle error...
                                  return;
                              }

                              if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                  NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                  NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                              }

                              NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                              NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
                          }];
[task resume];
```

The resulting JSON obtain from **body** is the following and as you can see there is a JSON within the JSON, how can I store **that** JSON in a **NSDictionary** as you can see that JSON is between quotation marks.

```
    [
        {
            tag: "login",
            status: true,
            data: 
            "
                {
                    "userID":1,
                    "name":"John",
                    "lastName":"Titor",
                    "username":"jtitor01",
                    "userEmail":"jtitor01@gmail.com",
                    "age":28,
                }
            "
        }
    ]
```

Comment: `NSArray *topLevel = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; NSString *lowLevel = [[topLevel firstObject] objectForKey:@"data"]; NSData *lowLevelData = [lowLevel dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSDictionary *final = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:lowLevelData options:0 error:nil];` or something like that could do the trick.

Comment: Yeah it worked, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in reality:
Classic JSON, where inside there is a String "representing" a JSON.

So, since we can do: 
NSData <=> NSString
NSArray/NSDictionary <=> JSON NSData
We just have to switch between them according to the kind of data we have.

```
NSArray *topLevelJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]; 
NSString *lowLevelString = [[topLevelJSON firstObject] objectForKey:@"data"]; 
NSData *lowLevelData = [lowLevelString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSDictionary *final = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:lowLevelData options:0 error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line of code

```
NSDictionary* responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:kNilOptions error:&errorJson];
```

it will help.thanks

Comment: @bayadi --  are you checked the URL is valid or not, check once and then submit your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)loadDetails {
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                _allVehicleLocationsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
                [self afterCompleteDoThis];
            }] resume];
}

- (void)afterCompleteDoThis {
    for (NSDictionary *vehicleDict in _allVehicleLocationsArray) {
        NSLog(@" PPP %@" , [vehicleDict valueForKey:@"vehicleType"]);
    }
}
```