# JSON data not getting Properly in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

I am fetching data from JSON using URL.
JSON Data come perfectly 
[image: JSON DATA code]

But When i use to fetch value from json data it gives null value to me.
i also tried podfile (SwiftyJSON) but still getting nothing.
Code With SwiftyJSON

```
 let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://einvito.com/login.php")!

      //  let url: NSURL = NSURL (string: "http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?ICAO=LSZH&username=demo")!
        let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        let bodyData = "mobile=8401405853 & password=shivam"
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
        {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil
            {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            // You can print out response object
            print("response = \(response)")


            do {

             // var anyObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) as AnyObject

                let json = JSON(data: data!)
                print(json) // Print JSON Data (Snap is there)
               let namenew  = json ["info"]["notusernumbers"]["userid"].stringValue
                print(namenew) // Print Nothing (Means null value got)
```

Comment: Did you tried NSUTF8StringEncoding for options in JSONserialization?

Comment: try `String(json ["info"]["notusernumbers"]["userid"])`, also it appears that your userid is already a string so why are you casting it to a string ?

Comment: It seems that the data in `json["info"]` is a string representing again a JSON. So you need to do `let infoJSON(data:json["info"].dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)) let nameNew = infoJSON["notusernumbers"]["userid"]`, or something similar.

Comment: It still Produce Null @AnthonyRoani

Comment: Your response is not perfect

Comment: I tried this code but it gives error value of json has no member dataUsingEncoding @Larme

Comment: I tried NSUTF8StringEncoding but it still gives Null

Comment: How You say this Response is not perfect .? @AshishKakkad

Comment: `json["info"] as NSString` or something like that. Then convert it to NSData with encoding. I don't speak Swift, I'm just giving the main idea of what seems to me to be the issue, which is the same as there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149110/parsing-json-within-json-in-objective-c/33149574#33149574

Comment: Thanks @Larme It solve my Issue.