# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Below is my code

```
   nameLabel.text=[[[dict_Details objectForKey:@"unknown_object"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"UserFullName"];
```

here is my response

getUserReviewsResponse

```
{
"status_code" = 200;
"unknown_object" = "[{ID:227,ServiceProviderName:Dr.KarthikMendi,UserFullName:karthik,ReviewTemplateID:19,TotalScore:88.0,ServiceName:Doctor,Review:Very knowlegable doctor he understands the problem very well.,ServiceID:5,CommentsBySP:Thank you...,ServiceProviderID:0,CommentByAdmin:null,UserID:106,Status:true,CreatedDate:2016-05-06T18:30:08,Services:null,ServiceProviderTypes:null},{ID:168,ServiceProviderName:Dr.KarthikMendi,UserFullName:karthik,ReviewTemplateID:19,TotalScore:92.0,ServiceName:Doctor,Review:I am very impressed.  Very organized and professional.\\r\\nI always leave feeling taken care of and medical needs met. \\r\\nNeed more Dr\U00e2\U0080\U0099s like him!\\r\\nGreat!  He gave me sufficient time!\\r\\nVery friendly, informed and hospitable. \\r\\nVery nice \U00e2\U0080\U0093 didn\U00e2\U0080\U0099t feel like a number, but an actual person.,ServiceID:5,CommentsBySP:Thank you,ServiceProviderID:0,CommentByAdmin:null,UserID:84,Status:true,CreatedDate:2016-03-23T10:12:19.087,Services:null,ServiceProviderTypes:null}]";
}
```

Comment: The value for key `unknown_object` is one big string, not a dictionary.

Comment: then what should i do now ?

Comment: If it's JSON (JSON within JSON as String), you may be interested with: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON Within JSON in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149110/parsing-json-within-json-in-objective-c)

Comment: The string seems to be JSON but is not because the double quotes are missing. Are you also responsible for the web service?

Answer (score 1):

The value for `"unknown_object"` is a string, but you are assuming it's a dictionary as you are calling `objectForKey:` on it.  Hence the exception.

In general I would say that JSON is "broken" as it requires double-deserialization, which is less than useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your json data in http://jsoneditoronline.org/ correct or not.

For example: Dr.KarthikMendi is string that include "Dr.KarthikMendi" (Double or single Quotation ).