# How to convert string to NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsarray

I have a `JSON` object and it has a key value pair like this

```
"AttachedDocument": "[{\"DocumentId\":354,\"DocumentName\":\"Screenshot_2016-04-15-00-35-11.png\",\"DocumentType\":\"image/png\"}]"
```

This value is coming as a string. How can I convert that into an `NSArray`

**FULL OBJECT**

```
{
    "LeaveEntryCode": 0, 
    "RequestId": 0, 
    "EmployeeCode": 17186, 
    "LeaveYear": 2016, 
    "LeaveTypeCode": 1, 
    "LeaveReasonCode": 0, 
    "BaseType": "ess", 
    "StartDate": "2016-10-24T00:00:00", 
    "EndDate": "2016-10-24T00:00:00", 
    "NoOfDays": 1, 
    "StartDateSession": "full", 
    "EndDateSession": "full", 
    "PreApproved": false, 
    "ForDate": "1901-01-01T00:00:00", 
    "Remarks": "test from Android", 
    "CoveringPersonCode": 0, 
    "AttachedDocument": "[{\"DocumentId\":354,\"DocumentName\":\"Screenshot_2016-04-15-00-35-11.png\",\"DocumentType\":\"image/png\"}]", 
    "RequestStatus": "P", 
    "Deleted": false, 
    "Status": false, 
    "CreatedBy": 0, 
    "CreatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00", 
    "UpdatedBy": 0, 
    "UpdatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00", 
    "DeletedBy": 0, 
    "DeletedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00", 
    "ModuleId": 2, 
    "ObjectId": 20, 
    "StartDateString": "10/24/2016", 
    "EndDateString": "10/24/2016", 
    "LeaveDayList": [
        "10/24/2016-FH,10/24/2016-SH"
    ], 
    "SystemLeaveTypeCode": "ANN", 
    "LeaveTypeName": "ANNUAL", 
    "Employee": null, 
    "LieuDayList": null, 
    "BaseLeaveType": "ANN", 
    "CoveringPersonName": null, 
    "LeaveReasonName": "test", 
    "DocumentSource": "LEAVE"
}
```

This is the full `JSON` Object im getting. I am getting this via a web service.

Comment: Where/how are you receiving this? Is it from a URLRequest? How are you getting the string in this format?

Comment: It's JSON String representation inside JSON. Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON Within JSON in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149110/parsing-json-within-json-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are getting `josn string` as response, so you can convert it to `josn object` something like,

```
 NSString *yourString = @"[{\"DocumentId\":354,\"DocumentName\":\"Screenshot_2016-04-15-00-35-11.png\",\"DocumentType\":\"image/png\"}]";

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                    error:&error];

   NSLog(@"json object : %@",jsonObject);
```

here `yourString` means object for `AttachedDocument` key!