# escaped json string on Swift

Tags: json, swift

In an iPhone app using SWIFT, I'm having to deal with a third-party API that sends a escaped string instead of a JSON object as response.

The response looks like this:

```
"[
{
\"ID\":3880,
\"Name\":\"Exploration And Production Inc.\",
\"ContractNumber\":\"123-123\",
\"Location\":\"Booker #1\",
\"Volume\":1225.75,
\"OtherFees\":10.0
}
]"
```

Up until now I have been dealing with this by manipulating the string to remove the unwanted characters until I get a JSON-like string and then parsing that as usual.

Angular has a handy function to deal with this:

```
angular.fromJson(response.data);
```

Java has its own way to deal with it. Is an equivalent function in Swift?

Comment: Not helpful in the short run, but maybe you should get in touch with them to let them know their JSON is broken? Maybe they're not even aware of it. May simplify things in the long term...

Comment: `myJSONString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\", with: "")` is not an option?

Comment: @Buffalo so you are currently unescaping the string. But what do you do after that? Process it as a dictionary? If so then the simplest solution will be to convert `String` to `Data` and then simply: `try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: stringData, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]`. But ofcourse it would be better to process it as a `Codable` model in which case its again just `try JSONDecoder().decode(MyModel.self, from: stringData)`. If either solution works for you then I shall post an answer with more details.

Comment: Isn't that JSON Stringified within JSON? Convert it into data, and convert it back into your object (with codable) or with JSONSerialization into an array.

Comment: Cf. Logic (in Objective-C): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149110/parsing-json-within-json-in-objective-c If that's already the top level, you can use `.allowFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing it to a dictionary then the simplest solution will be to convert `String` to `Data` and use `JSONSerialization`:

```
if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let responseArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]]
        print(responseArray)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

But ofcourse it would be better to process it as a `Codable` model in which case its again just as simple as:

```
try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
```

Provided that you have a valid `Decodable` model like so:

```
struct Item: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    //add the other keys you want to use (note its type sensitive)

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case id = "ID"
         case name = "Name"
    }
}
```

---

Lastly, avoid stringified jsons because its an easy source of errors.
Malformed strings or small/large deviations in the structure can go easily unnoticed.
Let the backend team know that they should follow a protocol in their API that its consumers can rely on.
By setting the json format, its essentially like a contract that showcases its content and purpose with clarity.
Sending a stringified json is simply lazy and reflects poorly on its designer, imho.