# get position in __NSCFString or __NSCFString to __NSDictionaryI o array in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get a json from an api and i Get it like this

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parseError];
```

this responseDictionary is like this

```
{
    information = "{\"firstName\":\"Will\",\"SecondName\":"Smith\",\"Male\":True,\"Age\":40,\"Description\":\"He is an actor\"}";
    message = "Hello I am Will";
    numberMessage = 32;
}
```

I need  to get "firstName" and I get "information" like this

```
NSObject *information = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"information"];
```

And i get this part

```
{"firstName":"Will","SecondName":"Smith","Male":True,"Age":40,"Description":"He is an actor"}";
```

But now, when I try to get firstName I can't because information is a __NSCFString

and I don't know how to do it, thanks in advance

Comment: You have another JSON encoded in string in information. Just decode it again.

Comment: but how? I tried and appear an error that say that in __NSCFString is not possible :/

Comment: `NSString *informationJSONString = *information = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"information"]; NSData *informationJSONData = [informationJSONString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSDictionary *informationDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: informationJSONData options:0 error:&parseError];` You have JSON within JSON. Redo it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing JSON Within JSON in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149110/parsing-json-within-json-in-objective-c)

Comment: I got it, thanks and after that i used id<NSObject> nameResult = informationDictionary[@"firstName"]; thanks alot

Comment: `id<NSObject> nameResult` => `NSString *nameResult`.